# Scope of variable inside a module in Fortran

Tags: scope, fortran, subroutine

I have a module:

```
module A
! derived data type definition
...
contains
  subroutine initialize()
  type(dtype), allocatable, dimension(:) :: var
  ! initialize the derived datatype variable "var"
  end initialize

  subroutine access()
  ! access derived datatype variable "var"
  end access

end module A
```

Inside the `main` program, both `initialize` and `access` function are called at different locations. Considering both functions are defined with in same module, can I access the initialized variables inside the `access` function without passing variable `var` into the `access()` function?

Comment: Very simply the answer is "yes", through _host association_.  I've suggested a duplicating question which goes into various detail of that, although it doesn't directly answer the "yes" aspect.  If you need more detail on why "yes" is the case, then please let me know (and edit more detail in to the example code).

Comment: Thanks! From what I see from the duplicating question, it is not directly answering the question as you mentioned. So I wonder if my question is really a duplicate.

Comment: Does it still hold even if the derived type variables are dynamically allocated inside the `initialize()` function?

Comment: If you want specifics, then please add them to the question.  As it is, the code has _no_ module or local variables at all!

Comment: Any module variable is accessible in the module's procedures (unless a Fortran 2018 `import` statement blocks that).  It doesn't matter whether of derived type, or allocatable (etc).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199534/discussion-between-sathish-sanjeevi-and-francescalus).

Answer (score 4):

There are three *scoping units* in the code of the question:

- the module `A`
- the module procedure `initialize`
- the module procedure `access`

*Host* association means that variables (entities) declared in the module scoping unit are accessible in the two module procedures.  However, a variable declared in a module procedure is not accessible in another module procedure.

That is, even though the *type* `dtype` is declared in the module (and available in `initialize`) the *variable* var is local to that procedure.  Again `dtype` is accessible in `access` but the variable `var` is not.

To be accessible in both procedures `var` should be declared in the module scope.